# Equation of a stretched-squeezed limaçon!

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I have a limaçon with the polar equation $r=a+b\cos(\theta)$. I want to strecth it in the direction of the vector $W=(c,d)$ and squeeze it in the opposite direction of $W$. I have a figure here which may help. The black one is the origin limaçon and the green one is the squeezed and sctetched one. Here $a=3.2$ and $b=2$.
[image]

There is a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164299/equation-of-a-stretched-lima%C3%A7on/4164963?noredirect=1#comment8631731_4164963) for the case that I squeeze or scretch in the direction of $W$.

Now, the question is:

> what would be the equation of this new closed curve? will this new closed curve still will be a limaçon?

I will appreciate any comment or solutions.

Comment: Please define precisely what your stretch/squeeze does at angle $\theta$ (measured starting at $W$).

Comment: @TedShifrin I still do not know what to say about what happens exactly at the angle $\theta$. But generally, imagine that you put some force on the limaçon in the direction of $W$. It makes the limaçon be scretched in the direction of $W$ and squeezed in the opposite direction. I tried to make it clear in the figure.

Comment: What's your definition of a _limaçon_?

Comment: Something that I can write in the form of r=a+bcos(t)!

Comment: In what way is this question different from the previous ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you; I wasn't aware there _was_ [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164299/equation-of-a-stretched-lima%c3%a7on). :S

Comment: @YvesDaoust in the previous question the answer is for the case that we have the limaçon streched or squeezed in the direction of $W$. Now here I want to see the equation of the limaçon that is stretched in the direction of $W$ and at the same time is squeezed in the opposite direction. I trierd to show it in the picture.

Comment: Unsure what you call stretch and squeeze, but IMO stretching in one direction is the same as squeezing in the other.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: No, a stretched limaçon is not a limaçon.

---

Let's be a bit more "generous" and call a *limaçon* any polar graph
$$
r = a + b\cos(t + t_{0}),
$$
i.e., that can be obtained by rotating the polar graph $r = a + b\cos t$ about the origin by $t_{0}$. A general limaçon therefore has parametric form
\begin{align*}
  x(t) &= (a + b\cos(t + t_{0}))\cos t, \\
  y(t) &= (a + b\cos(t + t_{0}))\sin t.
\end{align*}

It appears *stretching* amounts to applying a specific "orthogonally diagonalizable" linear transformation. Again, let's be more flexible and assume we're allowed to apply an *arbitrary* invertible linear transformation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    u \\
    v \\
  \end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
  \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x \\
    y \\
  \end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    Ax + By \\
    Cx + Dy \\
  \end{array}\right],\quad
AD - BC \neq 0.
$$
The parametric equations for a "stretched" limaçon are therefore
\begin{align*}
  u(t) &= (a + b\cos t)(A\cos t + B\sin t), \\
  v(t) &= (a + b\cos t)(C\cos t + D\sin t).
\end{align*}
This is not a "limaçon" in the stated sense unless the linear transformation is a Euclidean motion (rotation about the origin or reflection about a line through the origin) followed by scaling about the origin: We must have
\begin{align*}
  A\cos t + B\sin t &= E\cos(t + t'), \\
  C\cos t + D\sin t &= E\sin(t + t')
\end{align*}
for some real $E$ and $t'$. The remaining details are a little tedious to write out, but follow from addition formulas for the trig functions, which lead to $A^{2} + B^{2} = E^{2} = C^{2} + D^{2}$ and $AC + BD = 0$, so that the transformation matrix has orthogonal columns of equal length.

As for the equations of the transformed curve, multiplying the equation of the limaçon by $r$ gives
$$
x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2} = ar + br\cos t = ar + bx.
$$
Rearranging and squaring,
$$
(x^{2} + y^{2} - bx)^{2} = (ar)^{2} = a^{2}(x^{2} + y^{2}).
$$
This quartic equation in $(x, y)$ may be expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$ by noting that
\begin{align*}
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      x \\
      y \\
    \end{array}\right]
  &= \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
      A & B \\
      C & D \\
    \end{array}\right]^{-1}
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      u \\
      v \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{AD - BC} \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
      D & -B \\
      -C & A \\
    \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      u \\
      v \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{AD - BC} \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      Du - Bv \\
      Av - Cu \\
    \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
The details are again a bit tedious, but the result is a quartic polynomial, and the zero locus has the same qualitative shape (e.g., a cusp or crossing at the origin becomes a cusp or crossing at the origin) even if it is not strictly a limaçon.

Comment: D.Hwang Thanks a lot. But how we can consider the stretch and squeeze at this equation? I am looking for some strecth in the direction of $W$ and some squeeze in the oppsoite direction.

Comment: This answer shows generally: If we apply a linear transformation to a limaçon we do not get a limaçon unless we act by a Euclidean motion followed by scaling. The stretching of your first question and the stretch-and-compress of this question are the special cases where $-t_{0} = \theta$ (the angle of $W$) and $B = C = 0$. <> As Yves says, this question ($A > 1$, $0 < D < 1$) is not that different from your first ($A > 1$, $D = 1$).

Comment: The answer that you have provided is really interesting, But it does not sovle my question.