# equation for irregular shapes and determining their similarity

Tags: geometry

I am a biologist interested in studying cell shape. Cells comes in all different shapes and forms. Some are circular and oval but most have a shape that could be asymmetrical or irregular. A circle and an oval have specific equations. Is it possible to create an equation of a shape like for example the fifth one in the image?

I would also like to know if different cell shapes are similar, by that I mean if they could change into one another just by stretching, squeezing, twisting or bending or they are dissimilar, which mean one would need to do something else?

In addition, cells change their shape through time, a circle can become an oval and back to circle as the cell moves. Is there a part of math that study changes of shape through time?

Sorry that my question is not precise, I'd appreciate any help, for example, which books or branch of mathematics I should look into and try to find experts in, to find answer for such questions?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think this are topological homemorphic to the disk or sphere if you are in 3d.  Are there any holes in it?

Comment: Not in these ones. I am studying cell shapes across large array of organisms and I am sure I will find some with holes in them. I'm looking for a way to determine if for example cell 1 is topologically homeomorphic with cell 2? what are the techniques to do that?

Comment: If you do not tear the disk (first cell), namely you just squeez,  or bend then everything is homeomorfic.  To find the exact map from one to another I think is a difficult thing. On the other hand all you need to know is how to make a circle to the curve that represents the boundary of every other cell.  Maybe bezier curves are helpful.  As I am not expert,  Please wait for another also opinion,  after reading these comments.

Comment: Are you talking about 2 dimensional shape or 3 dimensional shape?  Are your shapes cross-sectional (tomographic) views of a 3d shape or shadows of 3d shapes?  In either case the exact same 3d shape can have a variety of 2d cross section or 2d projection shapes, as consideration of slices or projections of watermelons, bananas, etc, indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this question extremely interesting, but at the same time it's evident that it's also very complicated. On the other hand, I believe that the winning strategy is always to start from something simple and then, once consolidated, generalize it at will until you reach your goals.

So, assuming that I'm not an expert in the field, what I can say is that it often happens that we've a set of points to which we want to associate a function in one or more variables that describes them in the best possible way. A first question to ask is whether we want a function that passes absolutely through these points (*interpolation*) or if we want a function that passes us as close as possible, not necessarily that touches all the points (*fitting*).

In both cases, then, it's necessary to establish the *basic functions* to be used, usually *polynomial*, *rational* or *trigonometric*. Furthermore, it must be established whether this function is to be defined *elementary* or *piecewise* and in the latter case it's necessary to establish how to connect these sections, usually something smooth is desired, etc etc.

The answer to this list of questions depends on many factors, first of all the context in which one operates and the objectives we have set. Specifically, since the starting data may be affected by measurement errors, by noise, I would say that a *curve fitting* is preferable and in particular I thought that it was advantageous to rely on the *Discrete Fourier Transform* to quickly find a *least squares trigonometric fit* to the data.

---

In light of all this, by defining the following *routine* in *Mathematica*:

```
TrigFit[v_, m_, {x_, x0_, x1_}] := Module[{fc, fs, i, imax, j, n, p, t},
  n = Length[v]; imax = Min[m, Floor[(n - 1) / 2]]; t = 2 π (x - x0)/(x1 - x0);
  fc = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Cos[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  fs = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Sin[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  p = fc[[1]] + 2 Sum[fc[[i + 1]] Cos[i t] + fs[[i + 1]] Sin[i t], {i, 1, imax}];
  Expand@Rationalize[p, 0.01]]
```

we can begin with an *equally spaced distribution of points* of which we wish to determine a function in a variable with at most $m$ modes and defined on the period considered:

```
pts = Table[N[Cos[x] / (5/4 + Sin[x]) + Sin[x] / (5/4 - Cos[x])],
            {x, 0, 2 π - 2 π / 11, 2 π / 11}];

f[x_] = TrigFit[pts, 4, {x, 0, 2 π}];

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}],    
     ListPlot[pts, DataRange -> {0, 2 π - 2 π / 11}, PlotStyle -> Red],
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, GridLines -> Automatic]

TeXForm@f[x]
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

> $\sin (x)+\frac{1}{4} \sin (3 x)+\frac{1}{4} \sin (4 x)+\cos (x)-\frac{1}{4} \cos (3 x)$

Therefore, we can raise the bar by considering a *distribution of points* in the $\langle x,\,y \rangle$ plane of which we wish to determine a *$m$ modes parameterization of the closed curve* that best describes them:

```
pts = Table[N[{JacobiP[5, 1, 2, Cos[t]], JacobiP[5, 1, 2, Sin[t]]}],
            {t, 0, 2 π, π / 25}];

{x[t_], y[t_]} = TrigFit[#, 3, {t, 0, 2 π}]& /@ Transpose[pts];

Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}],
     ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red],
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, GridLines -> Automatic]

TeXForm@{x[t], y[t]}
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

> $\left\{-\frac{2 \sin (t)}{5}+\frac{2}{5} \sin (2 t)-\frac{8}{9} \sin (3 t)+\frac{25 \cos (t)}{4}-\frac{13}{4} \cos (2 t)+\frac{34}{7} \cos (3 t)-\frac{17}{9},\frac{584 \sin (t)}{97}-\frac{3}{4} \sin (2 t)-\frac{60}{13} \sin (3 t)+\frac{6 \cos (t)}{13}+\frac{44}{13} \cos (2 t)-\frac{8}{7} \cos (3 t)-\frac{101}{50}\right\}$

It's not all. The power of this approach is that it extends even to *closed three-dimensional curves*, everything always depends on having a set of sufficiently accurate coordinates. For example, in *Mathematica* we can find the coordinates of some *knots*:

```
pts = First@@KnotData[{8, 3}, "ImageData"];

{x[t_], y[t_], z[t_]} = TrigFit[#, 10, {t, 0, 2 π}]& /@ Transpose[pts];

ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> False,
                 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All,
                 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 70]]
                ] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 1/25, rest]

TeXForm@{x[t], y[t], z[t]}
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

> $\left\{-\frac{\sin (t)}{9}+\frac{2}{9} \sin (3 t)+\frac{1}{17} \sin (5 t)+\frac{1}{14} \sin (7 t)-\frac{\cos (t)}{8}-\frac{2}{81} \cos (2
>    t)-\frac{2}{11} \cos (3 t)+\frac{2}{23} \cos (5 t)-\frac{2}{43} \cos (7 t)+\frac{2}{71} \cos (10 t),\frac{\sin (t)}{9}-\frac{4}{11} \sin (2
>    t)-\frac{1}{8} \sin (3 t)+\frac{2}{57} \sin (5 t)-\frac{2}{57} \sin (6 t)-\frac{2 \cos (t)}{19}-\frac{2}{75} \cos (2 t)-\frac{2}{13} \cos (3 t)-\frac{2}{21} \cos (4 t)-\frac{1}{39} \cos (5 t)+\frac{1}{8},-\frac{1}{44} \sin (5 t)-\frac{1}{11} \sin (8 t)-\frac{1}{28} \cos (5 t)-\frac{2}{77} \cos (8 t)\right\}$

---

At this point, once we understand the academic examples, we can finally put them into practice by considering something similar to what you mentioned in the question. In particular, considering a two-dimensional figure with sufficiently well defined and closed edges, i.e. something like this:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

we can import it into *Mathematica* to extract the edge points:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpSbo.png"];
lines = Cases[Normal@ListContourPlot[Reverse@ImageData[img], Contours -> 1], _Line, -1];
pts = Reverse@SortBy[lines[[All, 1]], Length];
```

and consequently, by selecting the points of the three main edges, we obtain what is desired:

```
p = Table[TrigFit[#, 10, {t, 0, 2 π}]& /@ Transpose[pts[[i]]], {i, 3}];
ParametricPlot[p, {t, 0, 2 π}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

where, as an example, a *parameterization* of the orange edge is:

```
TeXForm@p[[2]]
```

> $\left\{-\frac{432 \sin (t)}{13}-\frac{29}{5} \sin (2 t)-\frac{14}{9} \sin (3 t)-\frac{1}{6} \sin (4 t)+\frac{8}{5} \sin (5 t)-\frac{76}{25} \sin (6 t)+\frac{13}{5} \sin (7 t)+\frac{19}{6} \sin (8 t)-\frac{3}{2} \sin (9 t)-\frac{2}{11} \sin (10 t)+\frac{48 \cos (t)}{5}-\frac{13}{4} \cos (2 t)+\frac{38}{13} \cos (3 t)-\frac{8}{5} \cos (4 t)-\frac{44}{15} \cos (5 t)-\frac{50}{11} \cos (6 t)+\frac{8}{13} \cos (7 t)+\frac{12}{13} \cos (8 t)+\frac{11}{7} \cos (9 t)-\frac{5}{6} \cos (10 t)+73,-\frac{41 \sin (t)}{4}+\frac{36}{7} \sin (2 t)-\frac{4}{3} \sin (3 t)-\frac{6}{5} \sin (4 t)-\frac{4}{7} \sin (5 t)+\frac{2}{3} \sin (6 t)+\frac{1}{7} \sin (7 t)+\frac{3}{5} \sin (8 t)-\frac{14}{11} \sin (9 t)+\frac{22}{21} \sin (10 t)-\frac{155 \cos (t)}{3}-\frac{48}{11} \cos (2 t)-\frac{22}{3} \cos (3 t)-\frac{26}{9} \cos (4 t)-\frac{4}{3} \cos (5 t)-\frac{2}{5} \cos (6 t)-\frac{52}{11} \cos (7 t)+\frac{5}{4} \cos (8 t)-\frac{4}{9} \cos (9 t)-\frac{1}{3} \cos (10 t)+\frac{1168}{9}\right\}$

Once acceptable parameterizations have been obtained for each edge of interest, we can proceed to work on the *change of shape* and in this regard I had spent [a fairly detailed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164963/247735). Of course, this will haven't solved all the problems, but I hope it's a good starting point. ^_^

Comment: I am almost in tears of excitement! This is amazing and as you said, a definitely great starting point. I need to learn a lot on the way and ask help but I now know where to begin. Thanks millions!

Comment: This is crazy, amazing! Thank you so so much! There is so much that can be done. I've asked our department to get me a Mathematica license and then I need to compile a set of cell pictures for analysis. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you so much again for adding extra explanations, this will help me so much!