# What is the most general form of a periodic non-reciprocal wave on a circle

Tags: fourier-series, wave-equation

I am trying to study shape deformations of a closed circle, which are periodic but non-reciprocal. A similar question has already been asked and [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409977/equation-for-irregular-shapes-and-determining-their-similarity). But I am now interested in studying the time-evolution in addition.
By periodic I mean periodic in time. I.e. After one cycle, the circle should have the same shape as in the beginning.
However it should also be non-reciprocal.
Initially I thought one could represent such deformations by considering two Fourier Series:
One in time and one depending on the angle.
While such a representation is cyclic it is unfortunately also reciprocal, meaning that it is invariant under time-reversal.
Do such deformations exist at all?
There are a few conditions that need to be fulfilled:

1. There should be no loose ends and if one plots the radius vs angle one gets a smooth function.
2. The function mapping the angle to the radius is single-valued for each angle.